# Autonumbering format based on value other cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to make a worksheet where one column automatically numbers based on the value of another cell.

If the cell in the first column says 'MSG', the value in the next cell, should be something like `MSGRA15_00001`, if in another row, the first cell is also `MSG`, the value in the next cell should become `MSGRA15_00002`.

If the value in the first column says `SEL` the returned value in the next column should be `SELRA15_00001` and so on...

[Cell numbering based on previous cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3BIC.png)

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your MSG/SEL-column is in range A1:A?, you can paste

```
=A1&"RA15_"&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$1:A1;A1);"00000")
```

Into B1 and then copy and paste it from there.

Comment: This works great! Thanks! Is there a way to keep the empty rows blank?
If the cell in the A column is empty, than the cell in the B column says 'RA15_00000'

Comment: you could wrap the existing code with an isempty() check. the cell will then not be empty, however, but an empty string (""). Code for B1:
    =IF(ISEMPTY(A1);"";A1&"RA15_"&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$1:A1;A1);"00000"))

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your help, this worked for me: =IF(A2="";"";A2&"RA15_"&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$2:A2;A2);"00000"))

Thank you very much! :)